# jQuery: Turn button filters into select menu options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Lever's job listing API, but in its current form, it uses buttons to filter the jobs by category. How would I be able to turn the buttons into a complete select menu?

In the Fiddle, the options are "Business Dev", "Customer Success", so those would be examples of options in the select menu I want to create.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emturano/gmuq0kxw/).

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="container" id="jobs-container">
    <h1>Open jobs</h1>
    <div class="jobs-teams">
    </div>
    <div class="jobs-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
url = 'https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/leverdemo?group=team&mode=json'

//Functions for checking if the variable is unspecified
function cleanString(string) {
  if (string) {
    var cleanString = string.replace(/\s+/ig, "");
    return cleanString;
  }
  else {
    return "Uncategorized";
  }
}

function nullCheck(string) {
  if (!string) {
    var result = 'Uncategorized'
    return result;
  }
  else { 
    return string;
  }
}

function createJobs(_data) {
  for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {

    var team = nullCheck(_data[i].title)
    var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
    $('#jobs-container .jobs-teams').append(
        '<a href="#" class="btn '+teamCleanString+'">'+team+'</a>'
      );
  }

  for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < _data[i].postings.length; j ++) {
      var posting = _data[i].postings[j] 
      var title = posting.text
      var description = posting.description  
      //Making each job description shorter than 250 characters
      var shortDescription = $.trim(description).substring(0, 250)
      .replace('\n', ' ') + "...";
      var location = nullCheck(posting.categories.location);
      var locationCleanString = cleanString(location);
      var commitment = nullCheck(posting.categories.commitment);
      var commitmentCleanString = cleanString(commitment);
      var team = nullCheck(posting.categories.team);
      var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
      var link = posting.hostedUrl;

        $('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
      '<div class="job '+teamCleanString+' '+locationCleanString+' '+commitmentCleanString+'">' +
        '<a class="job-title" href="'+link+'"">'+title+'</a>' +
        '<p class="tags"><span>'+team+'</span><span>'+location+'</span><span>'+commitment+'</span></p>' +
        '<p class="description">'+shortDescription+'</p>' +
        '<a class="btn" href="'+link+'">Learn more</a>' +
      '</div>'  

      );
    }
  }
}

//Creating filter buttons for sorting your jobs
function activateButtons(_data){
  $('.jobs-teams').on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
      var teamRaw = _data[i].title;
      var team = cleanString(teamRaw);
      var jobs = $(".jobs-list");if ($(this).hasClass(team)) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { 
          $(this).removeClass("active");
          jobs.find(".job").fadeIn("fast");
        }
        else {
          $(".jobs-teams").find("a").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          jobs.find("."+team).fadeIn("fast");
          jobs.find(".job").not("."+team).fadeOut("fast");
        }
      } 
    }
  })
}

//Fetching job postings from Lever's postings API
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  success: function(data){
    createJobs(data);
    activateButtons(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you make it clearer for me? so you only wanted to create a select with only 2 options e.g., **Business Dev** and **Customer Success**? and other e.g., **Design, Engineering ..** will be left as anchors?

Comment: @JF-Mechs I want a select menu that populates its options with whichever job category is available, the ones I listed were just examples. If you look at the Fiddle, you'll see the various job categories, and I just want them in a select instead of as buttons.

Comment: just fyi, just realized this morning i made a smal mistake in my example and maybe you didn't notice it. forgot to assign the ajax to a variable for doing exactly what i mentioned in the comments around it it should do, which is to ensure the call is canceled before being recalled, to ensure only one final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates I made are the following.

- Added `select` tag on jobs-team
- On the `createJob()`

  ```
  //get select element on the element with jobs-team css class
  $('#jobs-container .jobs-teams select').append(
     //append option.
     '<option value="" class=' + teamCleanString + '>' + team + '</option>'
  );}
  ```
- On the `activateButtons()`

  ```
  //get selected option.
  if($(this).find(":selected").hasClass(team))
  ```

```js
// Replace "leverdemo" with your own company name
url = 'https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/leverdemo?group=team&mode=json'

//Functions for checking if the variable is unspecified
function cleanString(string) {
  if (string) {
    var cleanString = string.replace(/\s+/ig, "");
    return cleanString;
  }
  else {
    return "Uncategorized";
  }
}

function nullCheck(string) {
  if (!string) {
    var result = 'Uncategorized'
    return result;
  }
  else { 
    return string;
  }
}

function createJobs(_data) {
  for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
    
    var team = nullCheck(_data[i].title)
    var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
    $('#jobs-container .jobs-teams select').append(
     '<option value="" class=' + teamCleanString + '>' + team + '</option>'
       );
  }
  //'<a href="#" class="btn '+teamCleanString+'">'++'</a>'

  for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < _data[i].postings.length; j ++) {
      var posting = _data[i].postings[j] 
      var title = posting.text
      var description = posting.description  
      //Making each job description shorter than 250 characters
      var shortDescription = $.trim(description).substring(0, 250)
      .replace('\n', ' ') + "...";
      var location = nullCheck(posting.categories.location);
      var locationCleanString = cleanString(location);
      var commitment = nullCheck(posting.categories.commitment);
      var commitmentCleanString = cleanString(commitment);
      var team = nullCheck(posting.categories.team);
      var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
      var link = posting.hostedUrl;
    
     $('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
      '<div class="job '+teamCleanString+' '+locationCleanString+' '+commitmentCleanString+'">' +
        '<a class="job-title" href="'+link+'"">'+title+'</a>' +
        '<p class="tags"><span>'+team+'</span><span>'+location+'</span><span>'+commitment+'</span></p>' +
        '<p class="description">'+shortDescription+'</p>' +
        '<a class="btn" href="'+link+'">Learn more</a>' +
      '</div>'  
    
      );
    }
  }
}

//Creating filter buttons for sorting your jobs
function activateButtons(_data){
  $('.jobs-teams select').on("change", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
     var teamRaw = _data[i].title;
      var team = cleanString(teamRaw);
      var jobs = $(".jobs-list");
      if ($(this).find(":selected").hasClass(team)) {
       if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { 
          $(this).removeClass("active");
          jobs.find(".job").fadeIn("fast");
        }
        else {
          $(".jobs-teams").find("a").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          jobs.find("."+team).fadeIn("fast");
          jobs.find(".job").not("."+team).fadeOut("fast");
        }
      } 
    }
  })
}

//Fetching job postings from Lever's postings API
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  success: function(data){
   createJobs(data);
    activateButtons(data);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
  
p {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.job {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #454545;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.job-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #454545;
}

.job-title:hover {
  color: #00A0DF; 
}

.tags span {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grayMediumDark;
}
.tags span:after {
  content: ', ';
}
.tags span:last-of-type:after {
  content: '';
}
.description {
  color: #999;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #999;
  border: 2px solid #ebebeb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #ebebeb;
  color: #555;
}
.btn.active {
  background: #454545;
  border-color: #454545;
  color: #fff;
}
.jobs-teams {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 0 30px
}
.jobs-teams .btn {
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.jobs-teams .btn:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.jobs-teams .btn:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container" id="jobs-container">
    <h1>Open jobs</h1>
    <div class="jobs-teams">
      <select></select>
    </div>
    <div class="jobs-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, the Fiddle is linked to jsfiddle.net

Comment: for some reason jsfiddle won't let me update your fiddle :) just added code snippet to add the demo

Comment: @eclipsis btw I didn't test this code much, it is for you to continue and have it work fully for you :)

Comment: you're welcome @eclipsis .. I am glad that it works for you, have a happy coding day! :)

Answer (score -1):

I see you got your answer, but figured I'd throw my 2 cents in and show you how you can, not only consolidate this code (<sub>*¡A LOT!*</sub>) but also make a lot better use of some jQuery methods you may not be aware of. No criticism intended, simply hope to show you another way that may help you work with jQuery better in the future.

```js
/** debug()
 * Simply for writing console messages as needed for testing.
 */
function debug() {
 try {
  window['console'] && (console.log(Array(100).join("=")), console.log.apply(console, arguments), console.log(Array(100).join("=")));
 } catch (a) {}
};

/** ajaxSuccess(data, status, xhr)
 * Easily seperated, and therefor easy to read/write method to use for success callback
 */
function ajaxSuccess(data, status, xhr) {
 debug("Success:\t", $([data, status, xhr]));
 var sorted = sortData(data);
 debug("Sorted Data:\t", sorted);
 prepHTMLContainers(); // ensure are HTML space is ready
 $.each(sorted, function(title, postings) {
  debug("Postings for ["+title+"]:\t", postings);
  // add select option for each category
  $('<option />', { text: postings[0].category, value: title }).appendTo('#jobsTeams select');
  $.each(postings, function(i, post) {
   // notice here, i do away with all that silly string building
   // jQuery has a lot of nice options for building HTML,
   // below is simply one of many ways
   var container = $('<div />').addClass('job').data('desc', { short: post.shortDescription, full: post.description }),
    aTitle = $('<a />', { href: post.url, text: post.title }).addClass('job-title').appendTo(container),
    pLocCom = $('<p />').addClass('tags').appendTo(container),
    pDesc = $('<p />', { text: post.shortDescription }).addClass('description').appendTo(container),
    aMore = $('<a />', { "class": 'btn', href: post.url, text: 'Learn more' }).appendTo(container)
   
   pLocCom
    .append($('<span />', { text: post.location }))
    .append($('<span />', { text: post.commitment }))
   
   container
    .addClass(post.teamClean.toLowerCase())
    .addClass(post.locationClean.toLowerCase())
    .addClass(post.commitmentClean.toLowerCase())
   
   $('#jobsList').append(container);
  });
 });
 $('#jobsTeams select').show();
}

/** prepHTMLContainers()
 * As stated, clean and clear HTML containers and ready them for new listings of data.
 */
function prepHTMLContainers() { $('#jobsTeams select, #jobsList').empty(); $('#jobsTeams select').hide().append($('<option />', { text: ' - Select a Category - ', value: '' })); }

/** sortData(data)
 * Sort data in a manner that makes creating the HTML easier
 */
function sortData(data) {
 var ret = {};
 $.each(data, function(index, item) {
  var catClass = trimString(item.title, true).toLowerCase();
  if (!ret[catClass]) ret[catClass] = [];
  $.each(item.postings, function(i, post) {
   ret[catClass].push({
     category: trimString(item.title),
     title: trimString(post.text),
     description: $(trimString(post.description)),
     shortDescription: $(trimString(post.description)).text().substring(0, 250).replace('\n', ' ') + '...',
     "location": trimString(post.categories.location),
     locationClean: trimString(post.categories.location, true),
     commitment: trimString(post.categories.commitment),
     commitmentClean: trimString(post.categories.commitment, true),
     team: trimString(post.categories.team),
     teamClean: trimString(post.categories.team, true),
     url: post.hostedUrl
    });
  });
 })
 return ret;
}

/** trimString(str, cln)
 * Simple and clean cut way to trim each string. Second param provides way to remove space if desired.
 */
function trimString(str, cln) { return !str ? 'Uncategorized' : !cln ? $.trim(str) : $.trim(str).replace(/\s+/ig, ""); }

// The first variable, "myAjax", will be used to ensure there's only ever one call to our ajax'd link
// The second is simply the options we'll use in it
var myAjax, myAjaxOpts = {
  data: "group=team&mode=json",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/leverdemo",
  beforeSend: prepHTMLContainers,
  success: ajaxSuccess
 };

// jQuery shorthand for document.ready
$(function() {
 $('#fetchData').on('click', function(e) {
  // by doing it like this (there's many ways to go about this, 
  // you don't have to use a button), we ensure that the 
  // connection is broken before trying to retrieve the same
  // data over and over
  if (myAjax) myAjax.abort();
  myAjax = $.ajax(myAjaxOpts);
  /** my general use of this doesn't rely on a global variable, but rather a local one
   * i usually just assign it to the element object itself, such as:
   * 
   *  if (this.ajx) this.ajx.abort();
   *  this.ajx = $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
   *  
   * */
 });
 
 // see how quick and easy jQuery can make things?!
 // the following line uses a "static parent" to assign an event to a "child"
 //  by doing it this way, the child can then be "dynamic" (loaded after
 //  page and js has been loaded) and still use the same event without
 //  need to "re-asign"
 $('#jobsTeams').on('change', 'select', function(e) {
  if (!this.value) $(this).children('option:eq(0)').text(' - Select a Category - '), $('#jobsList .job').fadeIn();
  else {
   var val = this.value;
   $(this).children('option:eq(0)').text(' - See All - ');
   $('#jobsList .job').fadeOut().filter(function(i) { return $(this).hasClass(val); }).fadeIn();
  }
 });
 
 // allows us to now toggle full descript
 // using .on to a static parent makes this work for all dynamically created children
 $('#jobsList').on('click', '.job', function(e) {
  var descShort = $(this).data('desc').short,
   descFull = $(this).data('desc').full,
   pDesc = $(this).find('.description');
  pDesc.html() == descShort ? pDesc.html(descFull) : pDesc.html(descShort);
 });
 
 // I moved the initial first call to here, as it appears
 //  the connection to OP's site has slowed up since first
 //  posting this answer.
 // JS is single threaded, but by using
 //  timers we can "temporarily emulate" multithreading and
 //  keep the browser from locking up on one piece of code
 setTimeout(function() { $('#fetchData').trigger('click'); }, 10);
})

/* Expected data return
 [
  {
   postings: [
    additional: String,
    applyUrl: String,
    categories: {
     commitment: Sting,
     location: Stirng,
     team:  String
    },
    createdAt: timestamp,
    description: String(HTML),
    descriptionPlain: Sting,
    hostedUrl: String,
    id:   String,
    list:  [
     {
      content: Sting(HTML),
      text:  String
     }
    ],
    text:  String
   ],
   title: String
  }
 ]
*/
```

```css
body { font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; overflow-y: scroll; }
p { margin: 0 0 1em 0; line-height: 1.4em; }
* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
section { position: relative; padding: 30px; }
.container { max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
.job { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 50%; padding: 40px 30px; }
h1 { font-size: 48px; color: #454545; padding: 0 30px; }
.job-title { font-size: 24px; text-decoration: none; color: #454545; }
.job-title:hover { color: #00A0DF; }
.tags span { color: #999; font-size: 12px; color: grayMediumDark; }
.tags span:after { content: ', '; }
.tags span:last-of-type:after { content: ''; }
.description { color: #999; cursor: pointer; }
.btn { display: inline-block; padding: 7px 15px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; color: #999; border: 2px solid #ebebeb; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; background: #f9f9f9; }
.btn:hover { background: #ebebeb; color: #555; }
.btn.active { background: #454545; border-color: #454545; color: #fff; }
.jobs-teams { margin-bottom: 40px; padding: 0 30px; }
.jobs-teams select { display: none; }
.jobs-teams .btn { margin: 0 8px 8px 0; }
.jobs-teams .btn:first-of-type { margin-left: 0; }
.jobs-teams .btn:last-of-type { margin-right: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fetchData">Fetch Data</button>
<section>
 <div id="jobsContainer" class="container">
  <h1>Open jobs</h1>
  <div id="jobsTeams" class="jobs-teams"><select></select></div>
  <div id="jobsList" class="jobs-list"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Enjoy!